# The `live` directive is not allowed on child or event bindings

Tags: javascript, lit-html, lit

I have the following code using lit-html.

```js
const textarea = (note) => {
  return html`<textarea>
    ${note}
  </textarea>`
}

let array = [1, 2, 3]


const rendered = () => {
  return render(html`
    ${array.map((item) => {
      return html`${textarea(item)}`
    })}
  `)
}
```

Executing the function rendered should be fine as is. However when I add `live` to the textarea here. I get the error in the title.

```js
const textarea = (note) => {
  return html`<textarea>
    ${live(note)}
  </textarea>`
}
```

Without live if I were to add a filter functionality to the list of text areas. A change in a textarea would stay even when html is re-rendered.

In other words.

- All textareas are visible.
- I make a change in the top textarea, adding "hello"
- I filter the textareas and do a re-render so that only the third textarea is visible.
- Even if I do a re-render, the word "hello" is there in the only visible textarea, even though it shouldn't be there since that textarea hasn't been edited.

Answer (score 2):

The issue turned out to be.

That you need to use

```
html`<textarea .value="${live(note)}"></textarea>`
```

instead of

```
html`<textarea>${live(note)}</textarea>`
```